# Can contract use its own ethers as a gas when calling other contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation

Can rich contract (that holds some ethers) use them as a gas when it would like to call other contract?

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html gives an example of `feed.info.value(10).gas(800)();` and I am not sure if 800 is deducted from originally send gas or from current contract's ethers.